# Callback function inside s3.getObject is not working - Node 12.x

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-s3, lambda

I am trying to get image from the S3 service, and resize it inside Lambda. I am using Node 12.x

```
    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
      console.log("inside getobject")
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else {
        console.log("let there be data")
        Sharp(data.Body)
        .resize({ width: 100 })
        .toFormat('png')
        .toBuffer()
      .then(data => 
        s3.putObject({
          Body: data,
          Bucket: bucket + '-dest',
          ContentType: 'image/png',
          Key: key + '-150X150',
        }).promise()
      )
      .then(() => callback(null, {
          statusCode: '301',
          headers: {'location': `${URL}/${key}`},
          body: '',
        })
      )
      .catch(err => callback(err))
      };           // successful response
    });
```

As you can see, i have console logs everywhere to see what part of the function is not working. It turns out that the callback function itself is not getting called.

For a clear picture, here is the log from the CloudWatch. No console log inside the code is getting displayed in CloudWatch log

```
2020-10-14T20:30:57.442+05:30   START RequestId: 06c20f38-444b-4932-9d2b-c650a4e12e57 Version: $LATEST

2020-10-14T20:30:57.459+05:30   2020-10-14T15:00:57.444Z 06c20f38-444b-4932-9d2b-c650a4e12e57 INFO Started

2020-10-14T20:30:57.459+05:30   2020-10-14T15:00:57.459Z 06c20f38-444b-4932-9d2b-c650a4e12e57 INFO hbjb.jpg

2020-10-14T20:30:57.460+05:30   2020-10-14T15:00:57.459Z 06c20f38-444b-4932-9d2b-c650a4e12e57 INFO serv-image-uploads

2020-10-14T20:30:57.499+05:30   2020-10-14T15:00:57.461Z 06c20f38-444b-4932-9d2b-c650a4e12e57 INFO { Bucket: 'serv-image-uploads', Key: 'hbjb.jpg' }

2020-10-14T20:30:58.180+05:30   END RequestId: 06c20f38-444b-4932-9d2b-c650a4e12e57

2020-10-14T20:30:58.180+05:30   REPORT RequestId: 06c20f38-444b-4932-9d2b-c650a4e12e57 Duration: 737.66 ms Billed Duration: 800 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 107 MB Init Duration: 584.66 ms
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: You should include the CloudWatch Logs for this Lambda invocation. Guessing that it timed out early because you have the default Lambda timeout (3 secs) set and that's too low.

Comment: My lambda timeout is 5 min. I think I'm capturing the full log there. Anyways I'll update the post

Comment: @jarmod The post is updated with CloudWatch logs

Comment: 100% sure that this is the actual code that is running? If you insert an additional console.log right before the call to getObject, does it appear in the logs? If you comment out all the code related to Sharp temporarily, does it make a difference?

Comment: yes it appears on the logs. I commented out all the code inside the getObject and still no luck

Comment: How are you importing the AWS SDK and what is `s3`? Both are missing from your code. I presume they are the usual suspects but it's worth clarifying. If you switch to the promisifed variant of getObject (`await s3.getObject(params).promise()`) does that work?

Comment: I'll upload the full code then

Comment: Also, force the AWS SDK to make logs using `AWS.config.logger = console;` It might help explain what's going on inside the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors... please tell me if with that solved your code works well

```
s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
      console.log("inside getobject"); // line was changed
      if (err) { console.log(err, err.stack); // line was changed
      } else { // line was changed
        console.log("let there be data"); // line was changed
        Sharp(data.Body)
        .resize({ width: 100 })
        .toFormat('png')
        .toBuffer()
      .then(data => 
        s3.putObject({
          Body: data,
          Bucket: bucket + '-dest',
          ContentType: 'image/png',
          Key: key + '-150X150',
        }).promise()
      )
      .then(() => callback(null, {
          statusCode: '301',
          headers: {'location': `${URL}/${key}`},
          body: '',
        })
      )
      .catch(err => callback(err))
      };           // successful response
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Didn't work for me though. I still don't see the console log

Comment: Thanks for the logs, you need to change your callback to a promise and need to have an await or lambda will response before you get the s3object or your put ... if you have time it's more easy manage that with python, but if not tray to not nest callbacks inside lambdas... get the response and after do de next callback

Comment: If you don't mind, could you show me how I can restructure the code, please? I am not exactly sure how to do it

Comment: Were you able to figure it out @SachinTitus?